# Can I control the execution order of VUnit testbenches?

Tags: vunit

I have several VUnit unit testbenches and a single top level testbench in my design projects. VUnit finds all my testbenches and executes them. I would like to control the order the testbenches are executed, so I can have the shorter testbenches execute first. Is this a feature available in VUnit?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such feature but it would be possible to create a script that takes the previous test report, extracts timing information and run tests one by one in timing order.

I think you should open an issue for this on Github to get better built in support. There are also other related features that would be interesting, for example load balancing when running multiple threads.

Comment: I've actually opened issue on VUnit Github page about the same thing. Issue is here and help is welcome: https://github.com/VUnit/vunit/issues/503#